# Notification - click fires wrong PendingIntent

Tags: android, android-intent, notifications, android-notifications

I have a notification with following content intent:

```
clickIntent = PendingIntent.getService(
                    getApplicationContext(),
                    Constants.REQUEST_CODE_NOTIFICATION_OTHER,
                    new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainService.class)
                            .putExtra(Constants.EVENT, Constants.EVENT_TOGGLE_BLACK),
                    PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
```

and one action with following action intent:

```
PendingIntent closeIntent = PendingIntent.getService(
        getApplicationContext(),
        Constants.REQUEST_CODE_NOTIFICATION_OTHER,
        new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainService.class)
                .putExtra(Constants.EVENT, Constants.EVENT_DISABLE_SERVICE),
        PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
```

When I click the notification, the close intent is fired. Why?

Here is how I create the notification:

```
NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
            .setContentTitle(getString(R.string.app_name))
            .setContentText(getString(text))
            .setStyle(new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle().bigText(getString(details)))
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_not)
            .setContentIntent(clickIntent)
            .setOngoing(true);

    boolean showCloseButton = MainApp.getPrefs().enableCloseServiceButtonInNotification();
    if (showCloseButton)
        builder.addAction(R.drawable.ic_close_black_24dp, getString(R.string.stop_service), closeIntent);
```

Comment: Try to change the code used by them.. both are using Constants.REQUEST_CODE_NOTIFICATION_OTHER

Comment: I just have this variable, because I've read that this should not be 0. I'll try that though...

Answer (score 18, accepted):

This is my guess... If does not work, I'll delete the answer...

I believe problem is that they are sharing same update number:

This is created:

```
clickIntent = PendingIntent.getService(
    getApplicationContext(),
    Constants.REQUEST_CODE_NOTIFICATION_OTHER,
    new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainService.class).putExtra(Constants.EVENT, Constants.EVENT_TOGGLE_BLACK),
    PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
```

Then, this new one is created:

```
PendingIntent closeIntent = PendingIntent.getService(
    getApplicationContext(),
    Constants.REQUEST_CODE_NOTIFICATION_OTHER,
    new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainService.class).putExtra(Constants.EVENT, Constants.EVENT_DISABLE_SERVICE),
    PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
```

It is similar to previous one and it is set `PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT`.
So, the second one UPDATES the first one.

Try to use a different code for different `PendingIntents`. Both are using `Constants.REQUEST_CODE_NOTIFICATION_OTHER`.

Then, Android will use that code to differentiate them.

Comment: you were right. System seems to reuse the intents if they share the same request id. Thanks

Comment: Good to hear! Glad I could help you

Comment: You saved me and my hair I was almost about to pull my already losing hair with this weird behaviour. Jokes apart I had two `Actions` in my `Notification` and both of them were firing only first one, the one I registered first to my `NotificationBuilder`. Providing different `RequestCodes` to both of them fixed the issue.

Comment: Man, what a disaster of an API. Shame on Google.

Comment: @W0rmH0le Can you show how you declared  `Constants.REQUEST_CODE_NOTIFICATION_OTHER` ? Thanks

Comment: @JohnJoe Constants.REQUEST_CODE_NOTIFICATION_OTHER was the original code from OP. You can define any constant like "public static final int REQUEST_CODE = 1;". You can define in the file that you want and use it.

Comment: @JohnJoe You can use any value that you want.. You just should use different value for different intents.. to differentiate them.